# SharePoint 2013 Save Conflict error on updating list item

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am having NewForm.aspx page of a list when user creates a list item I navigated to edit(EditForm.aspx) latest created Item.When User click on Save on edit Form with out any modifications it is throughing the following error.

Sorry, something went wrong Save Conflict.

Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.

Both New Form and Edit Form are custom Form Pages.

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know of no way to predict the id that Sharepoint will create for the new item. But could do so I also wanted to know.

But about your question, check for a running workflow to be created or altered. Because if you change some value in the workflow workflow changes will rotate.

I am available to help you.